# Pig - trouble with datafu's TransposeTupletoBag

Tags: apache-pig

I can't get the example code for LinkedIn DataFu's TransposeTupletoBag (at http://linkedin.github.io/datafu/docs/current/datafu/pig/util/TransposeTupleToBag.html) to work.

```
register datafu-1.1.0.jar
define Transpose datafu.pig.util.Transpose();

x = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (id:int,val1:int,val2:int,val3:int);
dump x
(1,10,11,12)

y = FOREACH x GENERATE id, Transpose(val1 .. val3);
2013-11-08 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: 
Could not resolve datafu.pig.util.Transpose using imports: [, java.lang.,
org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: pig_1383941559971.log
```

For some reason, Pig cannot find Transpose(). I'm able to use other DataFu functions, so it's not a problem with the JAR path. I'm using Pig 0.11.1 in local mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an easy fix. Either DataFu's documentation was mistyped or the API has been updated; Transpose() should be TransposeTupleToBag() (which makes much more sense, anyway). Just replace

```
define Transpose datafu.pig.util.Transpose();
```

with

```
define Transpose datafu.pig.util.TransposeTupleToBag();
```

and you're good to go.